# CSS flexbox: How to have same height title?

Tags: css, flexbox

Helo, can anyone help me with this one, i would like to lorem ipsum have same height in every li, but not max-height. When i have 4 line title i would like every titles have 4 lines height

```
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
    flex: 1 0 auto
}
```

here example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxvJqw

I want to achieve something like this, but not flex: 0 1 100px or something like this
I would like to be flexible, when the biggest title have 4 lines, all have 4 lines, when biggest have 2 all have two
[image]
I would be very grateful for help
Thanks

Comment: This is not possible. There is NO CSS mechanism for equalising heights between elements that do not share a parent.

Comment: Paulie_D in answer you gave me the height was hardcoded, no flex answer here, I wrote I don't want to have this hardcoded, but depend on lines

Comment: read carefully the other question .. first you need to understang that this is impossible with pure CSS [this is the important part]  ... then if you insist there is workaround or JS solution

Comment: Wanted to point out it's possible with CSS Grid `display: grid` but it's a bit complex.